# My question is regarding find(Node root ,int level) method. This the code about finding deepest node in given binary tree

Tags: java

In the find(Node root, int level) method ,the if(!=null) statement creates confusion for me. Suppose on reaching the last node of the binary tree, the left points to NULL. The statement find(root.left, ++level) recursively called find() method again. Now, the node points to NULL. So the if(root!=null) does not execute. Still, the code runs fine and the next line of code executes in the find() method. can anyone explain to me that when the if(root!=null) is false the whole if() block should be skipped ?

// Java program to find value of the deepest node 
// in a given binary tree 
class GFG 
{

```
// A tree node 
static class Node 
{ 

    int data; 
    Node left, right; 

    Node(int key) 
    { 
        data = key; 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
    } 
} 
static int maxLevel = -1; 
static int res = -1; 

// maxLevel : keeps track of maximum level seen so far. 
// res : Value of deepest node so far. 
// level : Level of root 
static void find(Node root, int level) 
{ 
    if (root != null) **//THIS BLOCK SHOULD BE SKIPPED** 
    { 
        find(root.left, ++level); 

        // Update level and resue 
        if (level > maxLevel) 
        { 
            res = root.data; 
            maxLevel = level; 
        } 

        find(root.right, level); 
    } 
} 

// Returns value of deepest node 
static int deepestNode(Node root) 
{ 
    // Initialze result and max level 
    /* int res = -1; 
    int maxLevel = -1; */

    // Updates value "res" and "maxLevel" 
    // Note that res and maxLen are passed 
    // by reference. 
    find(root, 0); 
    return res; 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 

    Node root = new Node(1); 
    root.left = new Node(2); 
    root.right = new Node(3); 
    root.left.left = new Node(4); 
    root.right.left = new Node(5); 
    root.right.right = new Node(6); 
    root.right.left.right = new Node(7); 
    root.right.right.right = new Node(8); 
    root.right.left.right.left = new Node(50); 
    System.out.println(deepestNode(root)); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If the `Node` parameter is null, it means we've run off the end of the tree and should "turn back".

The test for null has to go somewhere. Putting at the top the method means only having to code it once.

The other option is to code it *before* making the recursive call, so we never pass a `null` in, but then the test would have to be coded 3 times: once before the left call, once before the right call, and before the initial call.

`root` is a bad name for the parameter, it should be called `node`. Just because the first call to it passes in the root, doesn't mean we should name it that.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is searching recursively on your binary tree, in order to do that, you need to navigate through the nodes, and if you reach a `null` node, then you're not able to find further from that node.

So, basically you need to skip the whole block with the `if` because a null node doesn't have childs.